# How do I install asterisk-13.7.5 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, asterisk

I get this error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/src/asterisk-13.19.1/Makefile.rules:176: recipe for target 'chan_pjsip.so' failed
make[1]: *** [chan_pjsip.so] Error 1
Makefile:378: recipe for target 'channels' failed
make: *** [channels] Error 2
```

Please give us links to download asterisk server in Ubuntu 16.04!

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04, the package sources contain asterisk v13.1.0 and it can be install simply with `sudo apt install asterisk`. If for some reason you need a newer version, you can (roughly sorted from best to worst practice):

- upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 STS, whose sources provide asterisk v13.17.2
- wait a bit and upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, whose sources have asterisk v13.18.3
- use a `deb` package from [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=asterisk), e.g. [the 18.04 amd64 one](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/asterisk/download)
- download the latest version from [asterisk.org](https://www.asterisk.org/downloads) and install it as explained in [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/507051)